# ImageElement width and height always zero

Tags: dart

I have a quick Dart question. Is the width and height attributes of the ImageElement class not fully implemented yet? I can see they go in the constructor, but apparently they are not updated if you load an image dynamically, like this:

```dart
ImageElement image = new ImageElement();
image.src = 'whatever.jpg';
image.on.load.add((event) {
  window.console.log(image.width); // Will always print 0.
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code prints valid *widths* and *heights* for both PNGs and JPEGs.

Probably you have a buggy Dart SDK version. [Update your Dart SDK](http://www.dartlang.org/dartium/).

Or maybe the image path is wrong, try an absolute path like: http://www.dartlang.org/imgs/dart-logo.png

Comment: I know that the image is loaded, because I can actually draw it on a canvas. But I'll try updating my Dart SDK.

Comment: It turns out I was accessing the image before is was actually loaded.